# How to have multiple tables for a module in suiteCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In SuiteCrm,
I have 'doctor' module, in this module 
in 1st module I display doctors info such as name, speciality, experience etc.
in 2nd table, I want to show doctrs location with fields such as address, contact of hospital, state, city.
in 3rd table I have feedback received by doctor from diff.patient. 
like this I have multiple tables. 
Need multiple tables on list view page and detail view page for custom module created using module builder. Need to know how to add that.
currently only one table is there on custom module.

Comment: why you need more tables? add complete details so that you can get the desired help from the community.

Comment: so you can different modules for doctor and patient and then create appropriate relationship between them.

Comment: yes go ahead. will love to do that. Could you also help me with this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789860/file-upload-and-view-functionality-in-detail-view

Comment: I will review your other question and will try to post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can different modules for doctor and patient and then create appropriate relationship(one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many) between them.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to create Seperate modules for different table needs.

1) Doctor -> Person type module, this module comes with Primary address and alternate address widget, which is a group of 5 fields itself.
2) Feedbacks-> a Basic type module.

Until you dont' need M-2-M relationship between Doctor and Location, you should not create a separate module.

Hope this helps.